# Nuget push teamcity URL

Tags: nuget, teamcity

My I know what should I put in WhatShouldIPutInHere? I want to push my nuget to my team city server. it is on localhost:90. Thanks

[Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\packages\OctoPack.3.5.2\build\OctoPack.targets(109, 5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\packages\OctoPack.3.5.2\build\nuget.exe" push "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\TodoWebApp\obj\octopacked\TodoWebApp.1.0.26.nupkg" MyAPiKey -Source WhatShouldIPutInHere? "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can packages be published to a TeamCity nuget server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423272/how-can-packages-be-published-to-a-teamcity-nuget-server)

Answer (score 0):

A regular *nuget push* (what OctoPack is trying to do) is not going to work.

The TeamCity documentation [states](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/NuGet#NuGet-UsingTeamCityasNuGetServer)

> You can publish packages to the feed either as build artifacts of the NuGet Pack build step (using the Publish created packages to build artifacts checkbox, packages will be indexed asynchronously) or via the NuGet Publish build step (since TeamCity 2017.1, packages will be indexed synchronously)

Make sure that OctoPack only creates a package (and not trying to push it) and make it an artifact to add it to the TeamCity NuGet Server.